# gmake function / ifneq/else/endif

Tags: function, gnu-make

I am trying to create a function that will determine if a directory exist, and if it does, add a target to the all list.  but something is wrong.  Here is the Makefile code snippet:

```
define buildMQ  
    $(info ****     Checking to see if the MQ series directory exist     *****)  
    ifneq "$(wildcard $(MQ_DIR) )" ""   
        $(info /opt/mqm was found)  
        MQ_APPS=MQSAPP  
    else  
        $(error $n$n****     ERROR - The MQ Series direcory: "$(MQ_DIR)" does not exist     ******$n$n)
   endif 
endef

ifeq ('$(FN)' , 'TEST')
    TEST_APPS= 
endif

ifeq ('$(FN)' , 'ONSITE_TEST')
   ONSITE_TEST_APPS=  # insert ONSITE_TEST only apps here
   $(call buildMQ)
endif
ifeq ('$(FN)' , 'ACCOUNT')
    ACCOUNT_APPS=  
    $(call buildMQ)
endif
all:$(COMMON_APPS) $(TEST_APPS) $(ONSITE_TEST_APPS) $(ACCOUNT_APPS) $(MQ_APPS) makexit
```

and when I run it with FN = ONSITE_TEST:

```
****     Checking to see if the MQ series directory exist     *****
/opt/mqm was found
Makefile:128: *** 

****     ERROR - The MQ Series direcory: "/opt/mqm" does not exist     ******
```

How can both print statements get printed? What am I missing?
The directory does exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of misunderstanding here about [how `call` works](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html).  The `call` function takes a variable (name), plus zero or more arguments.  It assigns the arguments to `$1`, `$2`, etc. and then it *expands* the variable.

Note that by "expands" here we don't mean "interprets the variable value as if it were a makefile".  We mean very simply, go through the value of the variable and locate all make variables and functions and replace them with their appropriate values.

So, you invoke `$(call buildMQ)`.  This will not assign any values to `$1`, etc. since you didn't provide any arguments: in effect this is exactly the same as just using `$(buildMQ)`; the `call` function has no impact here.

So make expands the value of the `buildMQ` variable... basically it takes the value as one long string:

```
$(info ****     Checking to see if the MQ series directory exist     *****) ifneq "$(wildcard $(MQ_DIR) )" "" $(info /opt/mqm was found) MQ_APPS=MQSAPP else $(error $n$n****     ERROR - The MQ Series direcory: "$(MQ_DIR)" does not exist     ******$n$n) endif
```

and expands it.  So first it expands the `$(info ... Checking ...` function and prints that.  Then it expands the `$(wildcard ..)` and replaces that.  Then it expands the `$(info /opt/mqm ...)` and prints that.  Then it expands the `$(error ...)` and shows the message and exits.

If it hadn't exited, then you'd have a syntax error because a function like `call` cannot expand to a multi-line statement; as above it's not evaluated like a set of makefile lines.  It has to expand to a single value makefile line.

You need to use [the `eval` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) if you want make to parse the contents of a variable as if it were a makefile; `eval` doesn't take a variable name it takes a string to parse, so it would be:

```
$(eval $(buildMQ))
```

However, this won't do what you want for the same reason: it expands the `buildMQ` variable and that causes all the functions to be expanded first, before `eval` even sees them.

One option would be to escape all the variables and functions reference in `buildMQ`.  But in your situation a simpler solution is to use [the `value` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Value-Function.html) to prevent expansion before `eval` sees the value:

```
$(eval $(value buildMQ))
```

Comment: I think there is also a misunderstanding how `ifneq` works. I interpret [https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles] this way that using any of the conditionals will modify how a multiline variable is put together, it is not useful to create a conditional statement inside a function. To achive such, one must use `$(if )`, no?

Comment: Thanks.  The $(eval $(value buildMQ)) solved the issue.